# Target not found: mingw-w64-x86_64-flickcurl

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I'm using MSYS2, and I was expecting to be able to install flickcurl.

I tried installing as follows, but it seems that it can't find the file.

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-flickcurl
error: target not found: mingw-w64-x86_64-flickcurl
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Backstory: I'm following the build instructions for a Windows build of Darktable (photo editing software), and I ran into this. Been googling for a while, but couldn't find anything, so figured I'd ask in case I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your MSYS2 is outdated (think of it like Linux package manager which you update before installing stuff), you should run following commands and if you are asked to close terminal do it:

1. `update-core` - this one will fail if your MSYS2 is not very old, this is a good sign
2. `pacman -Syu` - you might have to repeat it until you see `there is nothing to do`; it updates your installed packages
3. `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-flickcurl`

Those packages should be available after those steps:

```
$ pacman -Ss flickcurl
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-flickcurl 1.26-1
    Flickcurl is a C library for the Flickr API (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-flickcurl 1.26-1
    Flickcurl is a C library for the Flickr API (mingw-w64)
```

---

### Commands explained:

- `update-core` - used in the past to upgrade core packages, now removed since `pacman` does it
  better
- `pacman -S <package_name>` - checks local database for package
  and installs it if it's found (will fail if there is no database or
  it's outdated)
- `pacman -Su` - compares installed packages to the
  database searching for updates (will also fail if there is no
  database or it's outdated)
- `pacman -Sy` - downloads database with
  available packages
- `pacman -Syu` - downloads database and searches
  for update, **recommend way of upgrading**

---

## Final note:

MSYS2 **doesn't** support partial upgrades for the same reasons as Like [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=System_maintenance&redirect=no#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported). That means you should run `pacman -Syu` before installing package.

Comment: That seems strange since I had just installed it prior to running the above command (that failed). `update-core` gave 'unknown command' or the like. There were a lot of updates though..

Comment: `pacman -Sy` downloads available packages database, without database pacman don't know which packages are available.